# How to extend Prism for MVVM boilerplate code

Tags: c#, .net, prism, mef

I am pretty new to Prism4/MVVM and wondering if there're any templates/extensions or frameworks which help in reducing the boilerplate code for adding the View, ViewModel, binding to DataContext etc using say Convention over Configuration ?

Ideally it'd co-exist cleanly with PRISM & MEF !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) can provide the boiler plate code you are looking for, like the ViewModelBase class and an implementation of ICommand (RelayCommand) that is good for biding to buttons etc.

Also using the [ViewModelLocator concept](http://blog.roboblob.com/tag/viewmodellocator) can be very useful and can be easily integrated with with MEF.